# Adding a prop to a specific React element type in any level of the DOM tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props, react-children

I'm trying to add a "position" prop to the 'Child' components and use it inside the 'Parent' component, So the only purpose of the 'PositionWrapper' is to add one prop and return the new children.
**The problem is that when I call props.children inside 'Parent' I get a 'PositionWrapper' component instead of 'Child' components as I want.**
I know that I can call props.children.props.children and I will get the 'Child' components but this solution doesn't look like a dynamic one (What if I remove the 'PositionWrraper'? Or what if add more wrappers?)

**Does anyone know an optimal/ a better solution?**
(or Am I implementing the 'PositionWraaper' correctly? )

Thanks!

The code:

**Child.js:**

```
const Child = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
        <p>my id is :{ props.id}</p>
        <p>my position is : {props.position} </p>
        </>
    )
}

export default Child;
```

**PositionWrapper.js :**

```
import React from "react"

const PositionWrapper = (props) => {
    return (
        React.Children.toArray(props.children).map((child)=> React.cloneElement(child, { position: [0,0,0]}))        
    )
}

export default PositionWrapper;
```

**Parent.js:**

```
import React from "react";

const Parent = ( props) => {

    // here I want to do things with children components of type 'Child' but props.children consists 'Wrapper' Component.

    return (
        props.children
    )
}

export default Parent;
```

**App.js :**

```
import './App.css';
import PositionWrapper from './Wrapper'
import Child from './Child';
import Parent from './Parent'
function App() {
  return (

    <Parent>
      <PositionWrapper>
      <Child id ={1} />
      <Child id ={2} />
    </PositionWrapper>
    </Parent>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you pass position prop to Parent - since you want to use it in Parent ?

Anyway, uou should use High-Order-Component for this scenario.

Check: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: High-Order-Component is a great suggestion! I haven't used it enough and it seems to work here well. Thank you :)

Comment: thumbs up my answer if you like it please

Answer (score 1):

You can do a complete virtual DOM tree search to pass the props only to a specific type like below. This is a simple recursive function doing depth-first traversal.

We process the children of the child and pass it as the third argument of [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement).

> React.cloneElement(   element,   [config],   [...children] )

```js
const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>my id is :{props.id}</p>
      <p>my position is : {props.position} </p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const PositionWrapper = (props) => {
  return React.Children.toArray(props.children).map((child) =>
    React.cloneElement(child)
  );
};

const Parent = (props) => {
  // here I want to do things with children components of type 'Child' but props.children consists 'Wrapper' Component.

  return passPositionPropToChildren(props.children, [1, 2, 3]);
};

const passPositionPropToChildren = (children, position) => {
  return React.Children.toArray(children).map((child) => {
    // Process the childrens first - depth first traversal
    const childrenOfChildren =
      child.props && child.props.children
        ? passPositionPropToChildren(child.props.children, position)
        : null;
    return React.isValidElement(child)
      ? React.cloneElement(
          child,
          child.type.name === "Child"
            ? {
                ...child.props,
                position: position
              }
            : child.props,
          childrenOfChildren
        )
      : child;
  });
};

function App() {
  return (
    <Parent>
      abc
      <h2>hey</h2>
      <PositionWrapper>
        <Child id={1} />
        <Child id={2} />
        <div>
          <Child id={3} />
        </div>
      </PositionWrapper>
      <Child id={4} />
    </Parent>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```